# AIX 6.1: CORE DUMP - GDB "thread apply all bt full" returns NOTHING?

Tags: c, gdb, aix

I am getting the following backtrace from a core dump from a C application on AIX 6.1. I am running GDB 6.0.

```
GNU gdb 6.0
Copyright 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "powerpc-ibm-aix5.1.0.0"...

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
Core was generated by `inbound'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0900000000b5c0a4 in _event_sleep () from /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0900000000b5c0a4 in _event_sleep () from /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
#1  0x0900000000b5c9bc in _event_wait () from /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
#2  0x0900000000b6a788 in _cond_wait_local () from /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
#3  0x0900000000b6ad60 in _cond_wait () from /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
#4  0x0900000000b52fc4 in pthread_join () from /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o)
#5  0x0000000100003d30 in main (argc=2, argv=0xffffffffffffb38) at ./inbound/inbound.c:850
(gdb)
```

When I try run **thread apply all bt full** it just returns NOTHING.

I am needing to find out the error here as it only happens in the following scenario:

- Application waits for messages for about 30 hours with nothing, then a message comes in and it seems to not like "waking up".

I would just love to see what is in my other thread that is causing the issue....

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Lynton

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core dump of multithreaded application shows only one thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077129/core-dump-of-multithreaded-application-shows-only-one-thread)

Comment: @ks1322 This isn't a duplicate of the question you referenced because on AIX GDB does not use `libthread_db` (which doesn't exist there).

Comment: Referring `warning: core file may not match specified executable file.`: Are you sure you use the right binary for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the gdb?  gdb is sorta hard / obscure to compile for aix.  For one, it has an option for AIX threads.  As I recall, you have to explicitly tell ./configure to use that option.

Also, as alk points out, be sure that you have the right executable <=> core file.  Be sure that you have the same LIBPATH, as the application did when it dumped.

fullcore helps as well (which I assume you already have).