# how to know state of the thread while debugging core dump with gdb on linux?

Tags: linux, gdb, signals, coredump, thread-state

i am getting crash in the thread. while debugging coredump with gdb, i want to see the state of the thread just before crash.

in my program i am raising a signal for that thread and handling it. it would be helpful to know the state before the thread has crashed and the time before the signal raised for that thread. is it possible to obtain this information from gdb?

Thanks

Comment: This thread has enough information about it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077129/core-dump-of-multithreaded-application-shows-only-one-thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this page

http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2009/07/looking-at-thread-state-inside-gdb.html

Comment: this is true.. but this works when actual program is running not with coredump.

Answer (score 1):

With "Reversible Debugging" of gdb 7.4 it is possible. Look [here](http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/28/tutorial-reverse-debugging-with-gdb-7) for a little tutorial.